# Merging rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
Line   VarA        VarB
345    Something   abc
346    Something2  def
347    Something   ghi
348    Something2  jkl
349    Something   mno
350    Something2  pqr
351    Something   stu
352    Something2  vwx
```

How can I turn this dataframe into something that looks like this:

```
VarA       VarB
Something  abcghimnostu
Something2 defjklpqrvwx
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [sum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
print(df.groupby('VarA')['VarB'].sum())
VarA
something     abcghimnostu
something2    defjklpqrvwx
Name: VarB, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, also how might I add spaces to each, like so "abc ghi mno stu" -- I will accept you when I can

Comment: You can add spaces in several different ways, depending what your final desired output is. You should probably post an other question about this with a little more details on the output you need.

Comment: I ended up doing 

    for i,d in df.iterrows(): \n    d['VarA'] = d['VarA'] + ' '

Comment: @MikeJohnsonJr You can also do this, df.groupby('VarA')['VarB'].apply(" ".join).reset_index()` as it was suggested by @jezrael earlier.